# Show the entire DataFrame if any filter is selected in streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I want streamlit to show the entire DataFrame when any filters are applied.

Here is the code I think will be useful enough:

```
df = pd.read_csv('classes_particulars.csv')

#Filters
idCode = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Selecciona un ID",
    ('ABSUDUHM', 'DWHWBMMX', 'MIXEECJR', 'NFKQWKOP', 'RQWLPVCJ')
)
preuPagat = st.sidebar.number_input(
    "Preu pagat"
)

dfSelection = df.query(
    "Preu == @preuPagat or ID == @idCode"
)
```

To show the `dfSelection` I code:

```
st.table(dfSelection)
```

However, I want to display `st.table(df)` if no filters are selected.

Here is what I have tried with a bunch of errors:

```
if df.query("Preu == @preuPagat or ID == @idCode"):
    df.table(dfSelection)
else:
    df.table(df)
```

The error I got is this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here is how the streamlit app looks like when using `st.table(df)`:
[image]

Here is how streamlit app looks like when using:

```
if len(df.query("Preu == @preuPagat or ID == @idCode")):
    st.table(dfSelection)
else:
    st.table(df
```

[image]
Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `len(df)` to check if something is filtered.
Also use st.table(df), and not df.table(df)

```
...

if len(df.query("Preu == @preuPagat or ID == @idCode")):
    st.table(dfSelection)
else:
    st.table(df)
```

Or

```
...

dfSelection = df.query(
    "Preu == @preuPagat or ID == @idCode"
)

if len(dfSelection):
    st.table(dfSelection)
else:
    st.table(df)
```

### Full code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data= {
    'Preu':[14, 15, 14, 12, 15],
    'ID' :['ABSUDUHM','DWHWBMMX','MIXEECJR','NFKQWKOP','RQWLPVCJ']
}

# df = pd.read_csv('classes_particulars.csv')
st.header('Dashboard')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Filters
idCode = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Selecciona un ID",
    ('ABSUDUHM', 'DWHWBMMX', 'MIXEECJR', 'NFKQWKOP', 'RQWLPVCJ')
)
preuPagat = st.sidebar.number_input(
    "Preu pagat"
)

dfSelection = df.query(
    "Preu == @preuPagat or ID == @idCode"
)

if len(dfSelection):
    st.table(dfSelection)
else:
    st.table(df)
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I tried what you did but I think it doesn't work because of 'preuPagat'. I believe when any amount of money is applied it takes 0,00€ as a number, so I do consider it as an applied filter...

Comment: Can you give an example dataframe?

Comment: I edited the question so you can see how it looks. I used your first answer to show an example. Hope it can help you to understand me. If more things are needed to clarify it, feel free to ask me out again.

Comment: I revise my answer, I added a full code with sample data. Check it.

Comment: Thank you!! I was dealing with this problem for weeks as I was learning streamlit from scratch. You can't know how happy a four-line code made me. THANK YOU!!!